# how to access value from array json object - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am beginner please help me to get value from the below array json object.

```
[{"Category":"HI","Sub Category":"AQ HIOP"},
{"Category":"2HJ","Sub Category":"AS HIOP"},
{"Category":"3HJ","Sub Category":"AT HIOP"},
{"Category":"4Hj","Sub Category":"AP HIOP"},
{"Category":"5HJ","Sub Category":"AN HIOP"},
]
```

I would just need the value of Sub Category

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `arr[0]['Sub Category']` to access the Sub Category of the first element

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of Sub Category"? There are 5 different values, which one do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to do it. If you have your Object in a variable you can access like this:

```
var test = [{"Category":"HI","Sub Category":"AQ HIOP"},
{"Category":"2HJ","Sub Category":"AS HIOP"},
{"Category":"3HJ","Sub Category":"AT HIOP"},
{"Category":"4Hj","Sub Category":"AP HIOP"},
{"Category":"5HJ","Sub Category":"AN HIOP"},
]

test[0]["Sub Category"] //Take into account that you have an array
```

In the case that you don't have any space in the key you can access like this:

```
test[0].Category;
```

If your JSON is string you must use JSON.parse before.

### Edit

Here you have how to insert to a new array

```
var another_array = []
another_array.push({"New category": test[0]["Sub Category"]})
```

Comment: Sure, you just need to declare a variable array and then use the push method to insert items in it.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to assign the output value to another array like below. another_array = ["New Category",test[0]["Sub Category"]]

Comment: Take a look to the edit of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var arr = [{"Category":"HI","Sub Category":"AQ HIOP"},
    {"Category":"2HJ","Sub Category":"AS HIOP"},
    {"Category":"3HJ","Sub Category":"AT HIOP"},
    {"Category":"4Hj","Sub Category":"AP HIOP"},
    {"Category":"5HJ","Sub Category":"AN HIOP"},
    ]
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     for (key in arr[i]) {
      console.log('Key: '+ key + ' Value: ' + arr[i][key]);
     }
    }
```

You can use `for` and `for in` to access to your Objet

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = [
{"Category":"HI","Sub Category":"AQ HIOP"},
{"Category":"2HJ","Sub Category":"AS HIOP"},
{"Category":"3HJ","Sub Category":"AT HIOP"},
{"Category":"4Hj","Sub Category":"AP HIOP"},
{"Category":"5HJ","Sub Category":"AN HIOP"},
];
test.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
})
```